# Linked List Program error in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I tried implementing Linked List using C++ using a structure. 
I've included three functions - Size, Insertion and Deletion from the end.
The program compiled successfully. During execution, when I tried to give input for the LLInsert() function, there was just a cursor blinking on my execution window. I don't know if the function returned to main.
Also the LLSize() doesn't return 0 when I try to find the Size of a empty list.
I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct LL {
        LL *next = NULL;
        int data;
    };

    int LLSize(LL *head) {
        LL *current = new LL;
        current = head;
        int count = 0;

        while(current != NULL) {
            current = current -> next;
            count ++;
        }

        return count;
    }

    void LLInsert(LL *head,int value) {
        LL *current = new LL;
        current = head;
        LL *Newnode = new LL;
        Newnode -> data = value;
        Newnode -> next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL) {
            head = Newnode;
            return;
        }

        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = Newnode;

        return;
    }

    int LLDelete(LL *head) {
        LL *current = new LL;
        current = head;
        int deleteddata;

        while(current->next->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next->data = deleteddata;
        current->next = NULL;

        return deleteddata;
    }

    int main() {
        int choice;
        LL *A;

        while(1) {
        cout << "1. Size\n2. Insert\n3. Delete\n4. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a choice : ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice) {
            case 1 : {
                cout << "\nLength = " << LLSize(A) << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 2 : {
                int value;
                cout << "\nEnter the element to insert : ";
                cin >> value;
                LLInsert(A,value);
                break;
            }
            case 3 : {
                cout << LLDelete(A);
                break;
            }
            case 4 : {
                exit(0);
            }
            default : {
                cout << "\nInvalid choice. Enter a valid choice " << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you had read [any good beginners book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) you should know about *references*. Think about that for a while, and go back to your books to read about it.

Comment: Read about member functions. Instead of `int LLSize(LL *head)` you should put `int size() const` into the `struct LL` block. Also getting the size should not create new lists.

Comment: It looks like you never initialized A. Your insert and delete pass by value.

Comment: Hint: `LL *current = new LL; current = head;` is just like `int x = 2; x = 8;`. There are many other issues. Read your C++ text book.

Comment: You are also supposed to `delete` everything you get from `new` and you don't do that. Luckily for you you don't need to and should instead read about  and use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which takes care of that for you.

Comment: You should research "C++ linked list example" and compare the results to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `using namespace`.

Create a type for the list and a type for the nodes

```
struct LL {
    LL* next;
    int data;
};

struct L {
    LL* head;
};
```

Use references and don't allocate new memory in each function

```
int LLSize(L& list) {
LL *current = list.head;
```

Check if the head of the list is set and use `nullptr`

```
if (list.head == nullptr) {
```

Use an instance of the list and not a pointer

```
int main() {
    int choice;
    L A;
```

Use a debugger like gdb to analyze your program.

Clean up at the end. Delete memory you allocated with `new`. One `delete` for each `new`.